# Overwriting Listview when adding a new object - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

**When I add an object from another activity using putExtras(), the Listview keeps overwriting with each new object. The list never has more than 1 item listed.**

What should I do so that when I create a new event it just tacks the new object onto a new position in the listview?

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;
int lastIndex = -1;
ArrayList<Event> lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

// detail view
TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
ImageView img;
View vw_master;

boolean _isBack = true;

ImageButton add;

String title;
String date;
String time;

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // // get detail controls
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
        break;
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        // do something with data recieved
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent.getExtras() == null) {
            // Do first time stuff here
        } else {
            // Do stuff with intent data here
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            title = b.getString("TITLE");
            time = b.getString("TIME");
            date = b.getString("DATE");

            Event newEvent = new Event();
            newEvent.set_date(date);
            newEvent.set_title(title);
            newEvent.set_time(time);

            lstEvents.add(newEvent);

            // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
            EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

            adapter.addAll(lstEvents);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }

}
```

}

Adapter

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView time;
    TextView date;
}

public EventAdapter(Context context, List<Event> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.date_detail);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Event event = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_detail, null);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.title.setText(event._title);
    viewHolder.time.setText(event._time);
    viewHolder.date.setText(event._date);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

CreateActivity

```
public class CreateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etTitle;
Button btDate;
Button btTime;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // /onclicklistener
    findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(this);

    // edittexts and buttons
    btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
}

// Will be called via the onClick attribute
// of the buttons in main.xml
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_confirm:
         String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
         String time = btTime.getText().toString();
         String date = btDate.getText().toString();

        Log.e("LOG", title);
        Log.e("LOG", time);
        Log.e("LOG", date);



        Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
        newBundle.putString("TITLE", title);
        newBundle.putString("TIME", time);
        newBundle.putString("DATE", date);



        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(newBundle);
        setResult(1001, intent);
        finish();
        break;
    }

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

}

Comment: you are starting a new MainActivity in every call to CreateActivity.  Thus, Main will only have that one result generated in create.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `startActivity` from `CreateActivity`, this is wrong... so the following code is not working.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(newBundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
```

Your `MainActivity` need to start your `CreateActivity` with startActivityForResult(). And your `CreateActivity` must return the result to the `MainActivity` using the `setResult(...)` function, passing an Intent with your Extras. Check the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29).

Comment: I updated the project to show all changes I have made. Am I on the right track? It doesn't look like it is allowing me to add anything to the listview now.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to add data to List You can add the Date to directly to the adapter Variable You will Add the data like this..

```
   adapter.add(Eventovalues);
```

Comment: This works, but it just presents the same issue I had initially. By adding the values to an array and than adding the array to the adapter it allows for more than 1 event to be stored.

Comment: I got it Your going to the new Intent means it will erase the all data from your list so it will lose the data you should maintain your Array List as the static variable and update the result

Comment: You will use the List variable like this     Mainactivity.list.add(evento);